# Converting strings to ints and ignoring colons

Tags: javascript, string

I want to convert two strings to ints to be able to compare them.

The strings are timers so I basically want to convert as below:

```
timer1 = 00:00:14 // 14
timer2 = 00:00:25 // 25
```

Comment: How would "00:10:00" be converted?

Comment: those are colons. Do you want time in seconds (e.g. 01:02:03 -> 3723 seconds) or just remove the colons and convert to ints (e.g. 01:02:03 -> 10203) ?

Comment: "Yes" ????? which one of the two?

Comment: @Jason S: I answered the first question, and now I see that I misunderstood it ;). However, to answer your question I actually don't think that matters, any would work.

Comment: Huh -- if you just want comparing for equality, why not compare the strings as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one is to remove the colons:

```
var str1 = "00:00:14";
str1 = str1.replace (/:/g, "");
```

Step two is to take the remaining number and turn it into a number. `parseInt` will return 0 for a string like "000014", so you can use parseFloat:

```
var result = parseFloat(str1);
```

Good luck!

UPDATE: I didn't consider the base 10 problem... this would work if you simply wanted to compare which time was greater, but to do a more "proper" comparison of real *times* you might want to convert both to formal `Date` objects first.

Comment: Actually, I just want to compare which time was greater so your code works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet removes all semicolons by means of a regular expression matching all occurences of `:` and converts it to a number using `parseInt`. If the string `timer1` was invalid, `NaN` will be the result.

```
numeric_timer1 = parseInt(timer1.replace(/:/g, ""), 10)
```

This fulfills your literal request for "converting strings to ints and ignoring colons".

If you're interested in converting `hour:minute:seconds` to seconds, split the string up with the `timer1.split(":")` method and apply maths.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
var s = '00:01:05';
var seg = s.split(':');
var hours = parseInt(seg[0]);
var minutes = parseInt(seg[1]);
var seconds = parseInt(seg[2]);

var total = (hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
window.alert(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using regexps and implicit string->number conversion (e.g. "7"*1 = 7)

```
function timeToSeconds(s)
{
   var m =  s.match(/(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);
   /* capture time fields in HH:MM:SS format */
   if (m == null)
      return null;
   else
      return m[1]*3600 + m[2]*60 + m[3]*1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare those strings as strings and things should work just fine, if those segments really are always 2-digit segments.